# PHP file not retrieving data from my mySQL database server

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently coding an Android app for login and registration. I have discovered that the error is coming from my php file as when I try and just open the file it does not fetch any of the data even though it is connecting correctly to the database.

This is my PHP code here:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("mysql7.000webhost.com","a3736257_root","********","a3736257_UD");

    if ($con->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    //echo 'connection successful';

$username = 'jack';
$password = 'jackjack';

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM Parent WHERE username = ?  AND password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute;

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement,$parentID ,$username, $password, $email, $created, $rewardOwed);
$parent = array();

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)) {
    $parent[username] = $username;
    $parent[password] = $password;
            $parent[email] = $email;
            $parent[created] = $created;
}
echo json_encode($parent);

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

This is the output when I execute the code

[image]

Comment: Try adding `mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);` in place of `mysqli_stmt_execute;`. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php Anything in the error logs? What does the source of that page show? The indexes of `$parent` should also be quoted.

Comment: When you debug the app, what is the error this PHP script is returning?

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

This is the error I get when I try to debug the app

Comment: Ye I tried yours and it worked for when I manually entered the username and password, trying it on the emulator now

Comment: Okay, I'll post as an answer. If the emulator fails it is a different issue with the emulator code (possibly how it sends the data).

Comment: `$parent[username]` `username` should be put into quotes unless  `username` is a `const` (`defined()` or via `class`): `$parent['username']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [mysqli_stmt_execute](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) function doesn't know what you want it to execute unless you provide it with the prepared statement. Also functions should have parenthesis `()`.

So:

```
mysqli_stmt_execute;
```

should be

```
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
```